# RatingBar looks bad

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am developing an Android application that uses a RatingBar, with 5 stars.
I have a HTC Wildfire, and RatingBar works very good. I have a layout for this screen.
However, I am testing in a HTC desire and it appears 4 stars, and it seems RatingBar doesn't work well.

I found a temp solution, adding this to the Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7"   />
```

And RatingBar works perfect, but another layout of an Activity looks now bad.
And in Wildfire, my layouts looks now bad too...

How can I do? Is it a bug of Ratingbar?

Comment: It's hard to help not seeing anything. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has bothered me....setting minSdkVersion="4" is effect.But another views may looks bad.
I’ve just spent far too long wondering why the RatingBar views in my Android XML layouts look different on the emulators, HTC Hero and HTC Desire. Small style rating bars seemed to have no concept of their actual size and the large rating bars for user interaction were clipped and falling of the edge of the layouts.

The answer is that the RatingBar view doesn’t scale properly on high density screens if you have the build target set to Android 1.5. The fix is to target API level 4, add screen support declaration to the manifest and then be careful not to break anything for the 1/3 of users still on Android 1.5.

Try setting the layout_hight of rating bar bigger:

```
       android:layout_height="20dp"
```

See:
    http://blog.csdn.net/prince58/article/details/6371389